# I need a prompt to show just once, save a username, and use it in the rest of the site

Tags: javascript, html, var, prompt

First post. 
I am really new at Javascript, so I may be asking a lot around here. 
Well, the problem is this: 
The user enters the site, a prompt asks for their name and then, the DOM is edited to show a 'h3' saying "Welcome userX".
But, the first problem was that, since the .js file was shared by every file of the site, it showed the prompt every time. 
To avoid this, I added the code in a function that is called when the body is loaded.

```
var salute = function(){
    var user = prompt("Por favor ingrese su nombre", "Usuario");
        if( user==null){
        user = "Usuari@ sin nombre"
    };

    var saludo = document.getElementById("saludo");

    saludo.innerHTML= "Bienvenido " + user; 

}
```

But, since I have this:
`<body onload="salute();">`
Whenever the user goes back to the "Home" they are asked for its name again. 
How can I do to avoid this? And aslo, is there a way to use the "user" variable in another part of the site? For example, in an image gallery, make it to say "We hope you enjoy this pictures, *user*"

Comment: MAybe, you can use cookie to store the info and change your code to check the existence of the username in cookie.

Comment: Or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But depending or requirements, you might need a backend to create a session and store the response in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to persist (localstorage) the username for next visits, and across other pages, then you may use this, and enhance it with additional validations:

```
var salute = function() {
  var user = localStorage.getItem("user");

  if (!user) {
    user = prompt("Por favor ingrese su nombre", "Usuario");
    if (user) {
      user = localStorage.setItem("user", user);
    } else {
      user = "Usuari@ sin nombre"; //Your default one
    }
  }

  var saludo = document.getElementById("saludo");
  saludo.innerHTML = "Bienvenido " + user;

}
```

Hope it works!